# steps to integrate .chm help file into java application (jsp page)

Tags: java, jsp, struts, chm

I created one .chm help file with help of fast-help software but not getting any solution for how to integrate that in my web project I created in java using JSP and Servlets in Eclipse IDE.

So,please help me out

Comment: CHM files are Microsoft's Compiled Help format.  I personally think it's a better idea to just have uncompiled HTML pages as part of your site.

Comment: My instructor told me to use CHM. I don't have any other choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following tool to create help file in CHM format.

http://www.helpndoc.com

Answer (score -1):

You could provide a link to this CHM file in your JSP page so that the user can download it:

```
<a href="/help.chm">Download Help File</a>
```

Comment: Any reason for this being downvoted? Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: I want to know where should i store the .chm file and how i will get this .chm file from fast help software

Comment: What is *fast help software*?

Comment: guys , answer please. It's very important for me. Thanks in advance.